# Can I access any response that is shown in dev tools?

Tags: javascript, iframe, response

Here is the scenario...

- I have an Iframe that is using RightSignature to capture a signed document.
- When I submit the document in the iframe, I can see in my Dev tools that I have a PUT with a json response that I want to grab.
- once it is submitted, the page in the iframe is redirected.

So far I have had no luck in capturing the response using just vanilla js and .addEventListener.  It seems like there should be a way to do it but I am just curious if what I think should be possible actually is.

So in short, if I can see the response in my Dev Tools, does that mean I should be able to capture it somehow using js, or because it is in an iframe does that not necessarily translate into something that is accessible to me?  I just want to know so I dont keep trying to go down a path that leads nowhere.

Thanks

Comment: Cross-domain iframes are protected from your site's JS (and CSS). They exist in complete isolation from you unless the owner of the iframed site explicitly sets up something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage or CORS to permit cross-domain communication. The dev tools are not subject to these restrictions.

Comment: Great. thank you.  I didn't want to keep beating a dead horse.  I will try to figure out some other avenue to try. Thanks again.